# SIM7000 "Normal Power Down" with AT+SMCONN or AT+SMDISC command

Tags: mqtt, iot, at-command

I'm making a project with a SIM7000A in Argentina, a tracker device for bee hives. It work over LTE Cat-M technology for IoT devices. I make a MQTT connection with a broker, everything is working. But sometimes happen a different behavior.

When the microcontroller send AT+SMCONN or AT+SMDISC via series, the SIM7000A responses is "OK" normally, or "ERROR: operation not allowed", if something is wrong. Both are ok. But sometimes, the response is "**NORMAL POWER DOWN**" or "**OK\r\n NORMAL POWER DOWN**". So, the SIM7000A is power off obviously. If i run the turn on rutine, it work ok.

I have done several tests, with Litio battery (5000mAh full charged), then a 12 V 30 A source. The SIMCOM chip work over a Shield + Arduino UNO, where is applyed the source. The voltage over chip is ok and there is not current limit.
The stranger thing is it doesn't happen all the time, and it's not suddlenly power off, it's a NORMAL POWER DOWN, as if I will sent AT+CPOWD=1\r\n.

Sometimes it work for some minutes and then the rare behavior happen, almost always when I make a signal loss simulation with a faraday cage, but it happen sometimes with good signal level.

I attach an example of the sequence. After executing the same routine successfully (without shutting down) several times:

```
cmd: AT+SMCONN
OK

cmd: AT+SMPUB="v1/devices/me/attributes",13,0,1
> 

cmd: {"GNSSStt":3}0 0 0 0 0 4 8 12 {"GNSSStt":3}
OK

cmd: AT+SMPUB="v1/devices/me/telemetry",36,0,1
>

cmd: {"Lat":-31.265165,"Long":-61.492058}
OK

cmd: AT+SMDISC
OK
NORMAL POWER DOWN
```

I await your prompt response, thank you very much in advance.
Santiago Mercante.

Comment: Please do not post images of text, post the actual text and format it. Images are hard to read, impossible for people that use screen readers and can not be searched.